Difficulty Updating Named Credential Parameters via Metadata API in Salesforce
I'm encountering difficulties updating a Named Credential using the Metadata API in Salesforce. Below, I've outlined the steps I've taken to create the Named Credential and provided the code snippet I'm using to update it, along with the specific issue I'm facing.
Steps Taken:

Creation of Named Credential
Created a Named Credential named "SentinelConnect Named Credentials" using Metadata API XML
The Named Credential includes parameters for external credential, URL, and authentication type

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NamedCredential xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <allowMergeFieldsInBody>false</allowMergeFieldsInBody>
    <allowMergeFieldsInHeader>false</allowMergeFieldsInHeader>
    <generateAuthorizationHeader>true</generateAuthorizationHeader>
    <label>Named Credentials</label>
    <namedCredentialParameters>
        <externalCredential>External_Credentials</externalCredential>
        <parameterName>ExternalCredential</parameterName>
        <parameterType>Authentication</parameterType>
    </namedCredentialParameters>
    <namedCredentialParameters>
        <parameterName>Url</parameterName>
        <parameterType>Url</parameterType>
        <parameterValue>https://connectapi.com/v1/</parameterValue>
    </namedCredentialParameters>
    <namedCredentialType>SecuredEndpoint</namedCredentialType>
</NamedCredential>

Update Attempt:
Using Apex, attempted to update the Named Credential's parameter value for the URL and other properties.
public static void getNamedCredentials(){
        try{
            MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createMetadataService();
            MetadataService.NamedCredential credentials = (MetadataService.NamedCredential) service.readMetadata('NamedCredential' , new String[] {'Named_Credentials'}).getRecords()[0];
            system.debug('NamedCredentials: ' + credentials);
            system.debug('endPoint: ' + credentials.endPoint);
            credentials.principalType = 'NamedUser';
            credentials.protocol = 'oauth';
            credentials.namedCredentialType = 'SecuredEndPoint';
            credentials.parameterValue= 'https://ok3kfo8y1m.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/';
            List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] {credentials});
            handleSaveResults(results[0]);   
        } catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Exception at getNamedCred: '+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }

Issue Encountered:
The code throws

common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Error occured processing component SentinelEMSDEV__SentinelConnect_Named_Credentials. At least one NamedCredentialParameter is required for NamedCredentialType: SecuredEndpoint. (REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING).

I'm seeking guidance on how to properly update the parameters of a Named Credential using the Metadata API in Salesforce. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Not answering your question, but should you not be using the Connect API to do this?

could you describe more about it? I mean How can I integrate it into my code?

Take a look at this Salesforce Developers video as a starting point.

it contains only how to create NamedCredentials , but in my case I want to update them , Is there any other resources for that.

Have you tried searching?

Yes .... I didn't found any for updating Named credentials through Connect Api. could you please share if you have it.

There are patch and update methods on the API for this. The payload is the same as you would use in the REST API.

Already took a look over both , they are useful for my case, But I am not able to implement a code for those , I mean , how can Initiate that method and how/what should I pass that requestBody to it and how I should include URL in that requestBody?
Please share any code example referrals for updating Namedcred using ConnectApi.

Have you looked at the documentation?

yes , but that even not providing any information on how to implement the updateCredential method of connectAPI.

It provides some example payloads that you would need to set up and pass. You can also find at least one code example if you search SFSE.

Yeah I setup the payload to update my NamedCredential URL , now to which specific uri , i need to pass this payload ? Do you have any document for this

The point with the Connect API is that there are no end points to be called; you use the Connect API's API to perform the required updates, like calling the NamedCredentials.updateCredential for example.

I initiated a InputCredential like this "        ConnectApi.CredentialInput requestBody = new ConnectApi.CredentialInput();"
It results all null values , check this debug
ConnectApi.CredentialInput[authenticationProtocol=null, authenticationProtocolVariant=null, credentials=null, externalCredential=null, principalName=null, principalType=null].

OK, so populate the details, then pass the populated input to the update or patch method.

to which attribute I need to populate value for specifically to update URL of NamedCredential

I'm thinking you need to be updating the external credential.

No, i need to update nameCredential. I gone through this "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_output_named_credential.htm" but check my debug of CredentialInput, it  doesn't contain any of  these attributes

Unfortunately I cannot think of anything else to suggest. Good luck in finding a solution. If you do, please make sure to post a self-answer here to help the next person.
